# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. in volley\bintray.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\aasim\AndroidStudioProjects\Project2\volley\bintray.gradle'
>     line: 25
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'volley'.
>
>   > Could not find property 'android' on task ':sourcesJar'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.696 secs

Comment: Did you try what it suggested about running the build with other flags to get more log output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very new in android. and facing the same problem from last few hours and got the way :

step 1: open volley gradle

step 2: find this line-

```
apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

step 3: and comment above line

step 4: sync your project